# HTA/HTML/VBScript/AD - Extract user information from AD using VBscript

Tags: html, vbscript, active-directory, hta

I'm trying to create my first application. I want to create a script that extracts some user's properties from Active Directory. I've created an HTA application, but it doesn't work. 
I really need some support from you.

Thanks.

And here is HTML code [for HTA app

Here is script details:

```
<script type="VBscript">

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objConnection.Provider = ("ADsDSOObject")
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.Properties("SearchScope") = 2
    objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT userWorkstations,sAMAccountName,Mail,name,DisplayName,distinguishedName,LastLogonDate, FROM 'LDAP://dc=NESTLE,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='user' AND displayname='" & VaR5 & "'"
    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
</script>
<hta:application
    applicationname="ADUCUserGrab"  
    border="thin"
    borderstyle="normal"
    caption="ADUC User Grab"
    contextmenu="yes"
    icon="aduc_sm.ico"
    maximizebutton="no"
    minimizebutton="yes"
    navigable="yes"
    scroll="yes"
    selection="yes"
    showintaskbar="yes"
    singleinstance="yes"
    sysmenu="yes"
    version="1.0"
    windowstate="normal"
>
</head>
```

And here is HTML code [for .hta app]:

```
<body topmargin="1" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="1" bgcolor="#000080" text="#FFFFFF">
<table border="0" width="640" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" height="110" bgcolor="#000080">
            <i>Enter the <u>userid</u> or <u>last name</u> below and click appropriate search.</i><br>
            <input type="text" name="StrUserid" size="20">
            <input id=idsearchbutton  class="button" type="button" value="Search On UserID" name="userid"  onClick="SearchScope">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" height="300" bgcolor="#000080">
            <Div id="BaseUserInfo"></Div>
            <br>
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="60%" valign="top"><Div id="AddUserInfo"></Div></td>
                    <td width="40%" valign="top"><Div id="AccUserStatus"></Div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" height="70" bgcolor="#000080">
            <div id="AdditionalOptions"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "doesn't work"? What should it be doing that it isn't? Are there any error messages?

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error__ and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: When I use the form from the .hta app to search for a user should be returned these values userWorkstations,sAMAccountName,Mail,name,DisplayName,distinguishedName,LastLogonDate for that user.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your first HTA app experience then you`re aiming too high. Simplify mightily until your button pops up a "Hello World" message, then elaborate. Make the message include something pulled from a free text field, build gradually.

Comment: Been there, done that. This is my first real project. I need some help with this :)

Comment: If that's correct then your code, as posted, is incomplete. Your Search button calls something called SearchScope which is undefined. That was what made me think this was your first HTA. That's too fundamental to be the problem you`re trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

now it should work :-)

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <hta:application
   applicationname="ADUCUserGrab"  
   border="thin"
   borderstyle="normal"
   caption="ADUC User Grab"
   contextmenu="yes"
   icon="aduc_sm.ico"
   maximizebutton="no"
   minimizebutton="yes"
   navigable="yes"
   scroll="yes"
   selection="yes"
   showintaskbar="yes"
   singleinstance="yes"
   sysmenu="yes"
   version="1.0"
   windowstate="normal"
  >
 </head>

 <body topmargin="1" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="1" bgcolor="#000080" text="#FFFFFF">
  <script language="javascript">
   var adStateOpen = 1;
   var ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2;
   function SearchScope () {
    var e;
    try {
     var objConnection = new ActiveXObject( "ADODB.Connection" );
     objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject";
     //objConnection.Properties( "User ID" ) = credUser;
     //objConnection.Properties( "Password" ) = credPwd;
     //objConnection.Properties( "Encrypt Password" ) = true;
     objConnection.Open( );
     
     if ( objConnection.State == adStateOpen ) {
      var objCommand = new ActiveXObject( "ADODB.Command" );
      objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection;
      //objCommand.Properties( "Page Size" ) = 1000;
      objCommand.Properties( "Searchscope" ) = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE;
      objCommand.CommandText = (
              "SELECT "
               + "CN, distinguishedName, sAMAccountName, description, userAccountControl"
              + " FROM "
               + "'LDAP://dc=NESTLE,dc=com'"
              + " WHERE "
               + "objectCategory='user'"
              + " AND ("
               + "sAMAccountName='" + document.getElementById( "StrUserid" ).value + "'"
              + " OR "
               + "displayname LIKE '%" + document.getElementById( "StrUserid" ).value + "%'"
              + ")"
             );
      var objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute( );
      if ( !objRecordSet.EOF ) {
       alert( objRecordSet.Fields("CN").Value );
      }
     }
    } catch (e) {
     // log error
     alert( e.description );
    }
   }
  </script>

  <table border="0" width="640" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" height="110" bgcolor="#000080">
     <i>Enter the <u>userid</u> or <u>last name</u> below and click appropriate search.</i><br>
     <input type="text" id="StrUserid" name="StrUserid" size="20">
     <input id=idsearchbutton  class="button" type="button" value="Search On UserID"  onClick="SearchScope()">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" height="300" bgcolor="#000080">
     <Div id="BaseUserInfo"></Div>
     <br>
     <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td width="60%" valign="top"><Div id="AddUserInfo"></Div></td>
       <td width="40%" valign="top"><Div id="AccUserStatus"></Div></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" height="70" bgcolor="#000080">
     <div id="AdditionalOptions"></div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: take an interest in this project https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartadmin
It's all in HTA